# Axis Client .NET Web Service: Parameters Null in WebMethod but in SOAP Request

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, axis

I have a .NET web service being called by an Axis client; however, for some reason all of the parameter values I am receiving are null. The client does not pass the SOAPAction attribute, so I need to set the Routing to RequestElement as follows:

```
[SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle=SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]
```

I have set the namespace same as the caller.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://aaa.com")]
```

The appropriate method specified in the SOAP Request is being called but still all of the parameters are null.

My method looks like

```
 [WebMethod(MessageName = "method1")]  
    public string method1(int param1, string param2, string param3)
```

This is what the request looks like

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
        <soapenv:Body>  
            <ns1:method1 soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://aaa.com">  
                <param1 href="#id0"/>  
                <param2 xsi:type="xsd:string">value</param2>  
                <param3 xsi:type="xsd:string">value</param3>  
            </ns1:method1>  
            <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:int" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">11</multiRef>  
        </soapenv:Body>  
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

However, in the method I get null for all the strings and 0 for the ints.. Any ideas?